# sql delete query with where, and, or laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hello i am building a delete query to delete an row out of my database in laravel and i came to this problem i need to find a row where ... and ... or ... and ...

So in normal php that would be

```
DELETE * FROM connection_requests 
WHERE `user_id`=$user->id AND `selected_user_id`=$id OR 
`selected_user_id`=$user->id AND `user_id`=$id;
```

(The first `and` belongs to the `where` and the second `and` belongs to the `or`)

now how do i do this in laravel

Comment: Wrap the `and` statements inside brackets `(` `)`

Comment: i have tried this in laravel DB::table('connection_requests')
            ->where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->where('selected_user_id', $id)
            ->orWhere('selected_user_id', $user->id)
            ->orWhere('user_id', $id)
        ->delete(); but that dit not work

Answer (score 2):

**this would be work try its**

```
  DB::table('connection_requests')
          ->where(['user_id'=>$user->id, 'selected_user_id'=>$id])
          ->orWhere(['user_id'=>$id, 'selected_user_id'=>$user->id])
          ->delete();
```

Comment: sorry for the late reaction i had to do something, this worked fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
DB::table('connection_requests')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($user->id, $id) {
        $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id)
              ->where('selected_user_id', '=', $id);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($user->id, $id) {
            $query->where('selected_user_id', '=', $user->id)
                  ->where('user_id', '=', $id);
    })
    ->delete();
```

Comment: sorry missed the semi colon in the first where clause

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it myself everyone thanks for thinking with me

```
 DB::table('connection_requests')
        ->where('user_id', $user->id)
        ->where('selected_user_id', $id)
        ->orWhere('selected_user_id', $user->id)
        ->orWhere('user_id', $id)
        ->delete();
```